# Searching and printing regular expression from a file in python

Tags: python

I am using following code in python to search for regular expression in the file, but it keeps returning 'None'. Not understanding what is wrong with it. 
(Edit- Adding full code)

```
def process_syslog(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:

        for line in f:
           link_down_match = re.search(r'Link Down on en0. (.*$)', line)
           print en0_down_match.group()
```

link_down_match, always prints 'none'. I am doing RE match for following line:

String to match: Link Down on en0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).

Basically the file I am searching contains multiple such lines mentioned above with 'Reason' being different in some cases (1-10)

This is how I am calling the function from main (snippet)

```
if current_file == 'syslog':
                curr_file_path = dir_path + str(current_file)
                process_syslog(curr_file_path)
```

What is wrong here?

Snippet from file I am processing:

```
Mar 25 06:33:34 ethernet: Status: Link Down on en0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
Mar 25 06:34:07 ethernet: Status: Link Down on en1. Reason 4 (Unspecified).
Mar 25 06:43:06 ethernet: Status: Link Down on en1. Reason 4 (Unspecified).
Mar 25 06:44:16 ethernet: Status: Link Down on en1. Reason 4 (Unspecified).
Mar 25 06:53:59 ethernet: Status: Link Down on en0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
Mar 25 06:53:59 ethernet: Status: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Unspecified.
Mar 25 16:17:36 ethernet: Status: Link Down on en0. Reason 1 (Unspecified).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated answer removing the old content:

```
import re

def process_syslog(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            link_down_match = re.search(r'Link Down on en0. (\w+) (\d+)', line)
            if link_down_match == None:
                continue
            print link_down_match.group()

def main():
    process_syslog("syslog.txt")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Current output:

> Link Down on en0. Reason 1
>
> Link Down on en0. Reason 1
>
> Link Down on en0. Reason 1

Comment: why do I need to use splitlines, if all I need to to is group extraction. What I am expecting in above code is extraction for group1: Reason, and group2: 1. Then after storing this value in link_down_match, I should be able to use it in 'if' statement, e.g: if link_down_match== '1': do something

Comment: okay so could you add the content of `current_syslog` in your question please. I had just one line reference and i assumed that it was content of a file with each line having similar data...

Comment: Just edited the code. Basically the file I am searching contains multiple such lines mentioned above with 'Reason' being different in some cases (1-10)

Comment: can you please add the content of `syslog_file`. Atleast a small chunk.

Comment: posted above in the original post

Comment: Checked your edited response above. It works fine when I read it from 'lines'. However, when i try to read it from the file, it throws an error. Error points to process_syslog function call from main() and some Attribute error for splitlines 'AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'splitlines'. (I am doing import re at the start of my code). Is there something wrong with the way I am calling the function and reading the file?

Comment: I have updated the answer to solve all the mystery. Hope it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `group()` to `groups()`

```
print link_down_match.groups()
```

Or

```
print link_down_match.group(1)
print link_down_match.group(2)
print link_down_match.group(n)
```

Comment: No it is not needed to change to `groups()`.`group` is just fine.Problem is with `current_syslog`

Answer (score 0):

Several things.

- though you didn't mention it, I suppose you have a 'with open...' statement before the for loop?
- are you sure you have *always* exactly 1 space before the (\w+) and the (\d+)?
- you printed the example text with colors in your example. I suppose this is something from Stackoverflow? Else there might be escape sequences in you log.

I tested the r.e. on your example and it runs ok here, so check the above...

Comment: I edited the code above and added more info. It should answer your question. I am also suspecting the way I am passing the file to the function is not correct, but not sure